# Questions about the proof of the isomorphism $k[X] \to \mathcal{O}(X)$ in the book Linear algebraic groups by Springer.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am reading the book [linear algebraic group](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817648399) by Springer. I have some questions on page 8.

Theorem 1.4.5 is: $\phi: k[X] \to \mathcal{O}(X)$ is an isomorphism.

(1) Line 8-9 of the proof of Theorem 1.4.5, it is said that we may assume that $h_x=a_x$ since $D(a_x)=D(a_x^{n_x})$. I don't know why we may assume that $h_x=a_x$.

(2) Line 14 of the proof of Theorem 1.4.5, it is said that the ideal generated by $h_1^2, \ldots, h_s^2$ is $k[X]$ since $D(h_i)$ cover $X$. I don't know why the ideal generated by $h_1^2, \ldots, h_s^2$ is $k[X]$.

Could you explain this more explicitly? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: I'd advise you to make your title more descriptive (i.e. try to formulate the actual questions). That way, you have a bigger chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: There's a bunch of "replacing **_ with _**" implicit in the passage.  Let's rewrite it.

> Let $f \in \mathcal{O}(X)$.  For each $x$ there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ and $g_x, h_x \in k[X]$ such that $h_x$ does not vanish on $U_x$ and
>   $$f(y) = \frac{g_x(y)}{h_x(y)}$$
>   for each $y \in U_x$.  **Replacing $U_x$ with a smaller open neighborhood if necessary**, we may assume that $U_x = D(a_x)$ for some $a_x \in k[X]$.  Then $D(a_x) \subseteq D(h_x)$, so we have
>   $$a_x^{n_x} = h_x h'_x$$
>   for some $h'_x \in k[X]$ and $n_x \geq 1$.  So for $y \in U_x$ we have
>   $$f(y) =\frac{g_x(y)}{h_x(y)} = \frac{g_x(y) h'_x(y)}{h_x(y) h'_x(y)}= \frac{g_x(y) h'_x(y)}{a_x(y)^{n_x}}.$$
>   Since $D(a_x) = D(a_x^{n_x})$, **we may replace $a_x$ with $a_x^{n_x}$,** so that
>   $$f(y) = \frac{g_x(y) h'_x(y)}{a_x(y)}.$$
>   **Now replace $g_x$ with $g_x h'_x$ and also replace $h_x$ with $a_x$**, so that the above becomes
>   $$f(y) = \frac{g_x(y)}{h_x(y)}$$
>   and we still have $U_x = D(a_x)$ and $h_x = a_x$.

**Question 2**: Well, if the $D(h_i)$ cover $X$, then the $D(h_i^2)$ also cover $X$, since $D(h_i) = D(h_i^2)$...

As an aside, my general feeling is that Springer's attempt to make the book totally self-contained by including all the necessary algebraic geometry is probably a bit too much for someone who doesn't actually know algebraic geometry yet.  It's probably far easier to learn the relevant algebraic geometry elsewhere.